# Android M doze mode and "native" posix socket freezing up

Tags: android, sockets, android-6.0-marshmallow

do not know if someone could help considering that Android M is floating around since not so much.
I am experiencing some strange behaviour with my app.
I am using native posix like tcp client sockets to make some connections.
These sockets are working well until the "doze" or the "app standby" modes do not activate...cause once they do either a phone reset can not allow my app to work once again.
The only solution is to clear the app data or to the reinstall the app on the phone.
I still have not investigated which is the errno of the subsequent connections, those after the doze mode, for sure it sound too strange that a complete app reinstall is necessary in order to fix the posix tcp connections to work once again.
Tomorrow I will be able to post few more details regarding this issue.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem on the Android M after that doze had prevented the network access?
Thank you!